# Ubuntu SQL Server Error: The evaluation period has expired

Tags: sql-server, ubuntu

I am getting the following error on my Ubuntu system

```
Error: The evaluation period has expired.

This program has encountered a fatal error and cannot continue running.

The following diagnostic information is available:



     Reason: 0x00000001

       Signal: SIGSEGV - Segmentation fault (11)

   Stacktrace: 000055a468212807 00007fcf4781b390 000055a4681e0e13

               000055a46820bc8d 000055a46820ab19

      Process: 1496 - sqlservr

       Thread: 1509 (application thread 0x1030)

  Instance Id: 04e490e6-14a4-4fc1-809a-58c660f8d341

     Crash Id:

  Build stamp: 94eba6a4633ca4c0df02f5ac93a5ec71d5e614105861a7140bd16aa838f6b2d7

Aborted (core dumped)
```

How can i upgrade my sql server installation in ubuntu without losing data ?

Answer (score 4):

As per policy of SQL server evaluation edition, the free license will expire every six months, I hope you have backup of all DBs or

One way:

> https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2015/06/22/sql-server-evaluation-period-has-expired-how-to-activate-sql-server/

The other way:

1. Take backup

> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/backup-restore/create-a-full-database-backup-sql-server

2. uninstall the sql server completely

> https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/174175/how-do-i-totally-remove-sql-server-2017-on-ubuntu

3. Check latest version of sql server for suitable to ubuntu version and install

Comment: Thanks for the heads up . Unfortunately there is no backup :(
When i try to start , that error is shown . Is there a way i can upgrade it to developer edition without uninstalling current one ?

Comment: Unfortunately none of above works. It gives same error for me even after uninstalling and deleting mssql files