# how to resolve sql server error on ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, sql-server-2014, ubuntu-server

how to resolve following error?

```
mssql-server.service - Microsoft SQL Server Database Engine
Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mssql-server.service; enabled; 
vendor pre
Active: inactive (dead) (Result: signal) since Tue 2018-01-23 17:21:28 IST; 4     
Process: 3319 
ExecStart=/opt/mssql/bin/sqlservr 
(code=killed, signal=ABRT)
Main PID: 3319 (code=killed, signal=ABRT)
```

Comment: Whats the result of journalctl -u mssql-server

Comment: This may help: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/156470/unable-to-start-sql-server-on-ubuntu-16-04

Comment: Jan 23 14:34:32 ubuntu systemd[1]: Started Microsoft SQL Server Database Engine.
Jan 23 14:34:46 ubuntu sqlservr[1130]: Error: The evaluation period has expired.
Jan 23 14:34:46 ubuntu sqlservr[1130]: This program has encountered a fatal error and cannot continue running.

Comment: "The evaluation period has expired." Then you may need this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47448374/ubuntu-sql-server-error-the-evaluation-period-has-expired

Comment: thanks Ruud Helderman

Comment: @RuudHelderman: Turn your comment into an answer for clarity!